# laravel - Google Analytics API Authentication

Tags: php, api, laravel, google-analytics, laravel-socialite

I am trying to create a web-app with a simple dashboard with Analytics data for the accounts who logged in with Google. I am using Laravel with Socialite package, and I can log the users in with Google currently. I have my developer client-key and client-secret. I set scopes for Analytics read-only, and offline access, and I store customer name, email, Google ID, access token and refresh token in my database. I can log the user in without any problem.

What I want to do is for now, just access the profiles an Analytics account currently has. I followed Analytics API documentation examples but could not get it working. Since I am storing an access token and a refresh token, I think I should be able to authenticate the current user and get their Analytics data, but I could not find any simple methods from the Client and Analytics libraries. I will need to access their Analytics data offline, and this is why I think I should be able to authorize my requests with access token and refresh token, but I do not get any Analytics specific data from user login process. I am completely lost now, how do I authorize my requests to Anayltics API? I have been using AdWords API for more than 8 months, and everything is crystal clear in AdWords API documentation, but I could not get anything working with Analytics API.

These are my user login methods:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    $parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];
    return Socialite::driver('google')
        ->scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])
        ->with($parameters)
        ->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from Google.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $outsiderLogin = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();


    $user = User::where('googleID', $outsiderLogin->id)->first();

    // Register the user if there is no user with that id.
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name         = $outsiderLogin->name;
        $user->googleID     = $outsiderLogin->id;
        $user->email        = $outsiderLogin->email;
        $user->token        = $outsiderLogin->token;
        $user->refreshToken = $outsiderLogin->refreshToken;
        $user->save();
    }
    // Log the user in.
    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution for now. At first, I figured that I needed the code that returns with authentication URL from Google, and when I inspect the Socialite package, I have found a protected method `getCode()` in `\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\AbstractProvider.php`, which returns the code from the URL. I edited the source file of the package and changed the method type from `protected` to `public`, and that made it possible to use that method outside of the class, which allowed me to access the code from the URL, then store it in DB for further authentication requirements. But there were issues with this setup, first of all, I should find a way to keep that package without any update, since any update will rollback the changes I made to the source file. The second problem I faced was the way I store tokens. By default, Google Client API returns an array which contains the fields `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expires_in`, `id` and `created`, and with these fields, it authenticates the requests to Analytics server. In my scenario, there were no standard array returning from the basic Socialite login process. There were `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `expires` variables and I stored them all in my database as well. This caused an issue with Google library, it asked for a structured array and I did not even have the variables `expires_in` and `created`, this is why I setup a fake array which tells Google to refresh token with every request, and this was not a good practice either.

At the end, I could not understand how to use any package online and I wrote my own simple authentication, and I do not know if it has any vulnerabilities, but it works for me, it may also work for those who needs it.

Here are my routes lines:

```
Route::get('auth/google', [
            'as' => 'googleLogin',   
            'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider'
]);
Route::get('auth/google/callback', [
            'as' => 'googleLoginCallback',   
            'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback'
]);
```

And these are the `AuthController` methods:

```
/**
 * Redirect the user to the Google authentication 
 */
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    // Create the client object and set the authorization configuration from JSON file.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('/home/vagrant/Analytics/client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/auth/google/callback');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("profile");
    $client->setAccessType("offline");

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    return redirect($auth_url);

}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from Google.
 *
 * @return redirect to the app.
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    // Handle authorization flow from the server.
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        return redirect('auth/google');
    } else {

        // Authenticate the client, and get required informations.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('/home/vagrant/Analytics/client_secret.json');
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

        // Store the tokens in the session.
        Session::put('token', $client->getAccessToken());

        $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
        $userInfo = $service->userinfo->get();

        $user = User::where('googleID', $userInfo->id)->first();

        // If no match, register the user.
        if(!$user) {
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $userInfo->name;
            $user->googleID = $userInfo->id;
            $user->email = $userInfo->email;
            $user->refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
            $user->code = $_GET['code'];
            $user->save();
        }

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/home');
    }

}
```

I have placed the `client_secret.json` file I have downloaded from Google API Console into the specified folder, this may be different for you. I have also modified the migration file in order to match the required segemnts. After these steps, I am able treat that user as it is a simple user that registered with the basic Laravel auth.

Now I can query, say, the accounts in the user's Google Analytics account like this:

```
/**
 * @var $client to be authorized by Google.
 */
private $client;

/**
 * @var $analytics Analytics object to be used.
 */
private $analytics;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = $this->AuthenticateCurrentClient();
    $this->analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);
}

private function AuthenticateCurrentClient(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = Session::get('token');

    // Authenticate the client.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    $client->authenticate($user->code);
    return $client;
}

public function GetAccounts(){

    try {
        $accountsObject = $this->analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
        $accounts = $accountsObject->getItems();

        return $accounts;

    } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
        print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
            . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch (apiException $e) {
        print 'There was a general API error '
            . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

There were thousands of times Stack Overflow has helped me, I hope this helps someone to get things working.

Answer (score 2):

You're not *really* going to find what you're looking for with the Socialite package shipped with Laravel (which is more used for logins and that's about it).

**You can however** find many Google Analytic packages (along with many other Laravel bundles) here which should help you make API calls:

http://packalyst.com/s/google%20analytics

More specifically, this package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics

That, or run your own Guzzle and cURL scripts. I use Guzzle when I need something quick without building a full blown API.

However, there's an interesting post here about using Socialite to access GA data. But you're quite limited. If you're creating user driven dashboards, I'd opt for a separate package.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-i-made-google-analytics-work-with-socialite

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I have seen most of these packages, but those packages seems to need a Google Analytics View ID which looks like `ga-123456`, and I don't think that this is a good user experience. As a user, I would like to have that web page get all the data without my additional effort after a succesful authentication. This is where things get complicated, I need to get data from GA, but there is no view ID or nothing comes with authorization process, this is where I got stuck. I have access tokens, but none of those packages work with that access tokens?

Comment: Socialite is NOT your answer. So you need to look at different options. I use this package for all my Google API services. But search Packalyst and find one you're most comfortable with. https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found my way with Socialite for now, and since I have a deadline for the project, I think I will use it as it is now until the MVP. I think I will migrate to the package you use, it seems pretty simple to use. Thank you, you helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'am also trying to do the same thing. By far, I've user authentication at place with oAuth 2.0 and `Socialite` package. I need the list of sites to be fetched from GA. And am totally stuck there. It would really be great if you can guide me as on how should I move on further..

Comment: Socialite is not the answer for this sort of authentication or API communication processes. You need to update source code of the Socialite package, which is not meaningful since you will need to redo your changes with every update. Socialite is just for simple login works where you just need the info of the user. Did you check my answer here? I have provided the code for fetching accounts. I am not sure if there is a direct way to fetch sites, but you can fetch GA Accounts, then Properties, which come with URLs for each of the properties.

Comment: Which code? All the code is up here, and the other parts of the code are business-related parts. You can login and get accounts report with those methods in the post. I can maybe create a gist or something when I got the time if you want.

Comment: Yes, please do. I also wanted to know about guzzle requests

Comment: if you can please post Google_Client(), Google_Service_Analytics and Google_Service_Oauth2(), It would be a great help

Comment: Those are from Google Client library, I did not write anything to those classes or methods. I checked my files and there is really nothing additional to the code above. What do you need specifically that I can help?

Comment: I tried them but they don't seem to work for me.. I'm using google/apiclient 1.1 what are you using? And also, are you using server application or web application credentials from google console api?

Comment: hi, sorry for bugging you, but if you can please tell me what file(where) do you query i.e the second code snippet? Please help me!

Comment: Here is a controller file that I have created. I get the user with oAuth, then with those information, I query the Google API Client library with the given codes, I think those may give you an idea. [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bbdd47ec13725fa4746da877d9369e96) And also, I have been working on a web app, so I have the credentials for a web app. Google API Client's composer require is "google/apiclient": "^2.0" for me, you should check their GitHub.

Comment: I did try composer require is "google/apiclient": "^2.0" but it clashes with socialite package (maybe I should drop socialite at all?) plus thanks for the controller, it looks perfect on your end but don't know why I'm stuck. If you can share your email id so that I can send you my files for you to have the exact idea please?

Comment: You should definitely drop Socialite first. But probably the collision was not because of that, I have used both of them at the same time in an app. You should check [Google API Client GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and follow the instructions in there. I can not provide my email, and I do not have time for debugging. This is a skill all of us must be mastering, so you need to find your way on your own with your code. If you can not solve it, just post it as a question instead of asking me, there are thousands of peopler better than me.

Comment: hi! I do understand and respect that. I did try as you mentioned. but while I try to fetch accounts in the other controller it throws error: Google_Auth_Exception in OAuth2.php:
Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request: Could not determine client ID from request.'  maybe you've faced it?

Comment: It looks like you did not set your client ID and client secrets properly. There is a JSON file that you download from Google API Console, called client secrets, in the Credentials page. You should download it to your directory, and then give it to the API with `$client->setAuthConfig('/home/vagrant/Analytics/client_secret.json');`, as the path is changed for you whatever your `client_secrets` file path. It comes as something like `client_secret12839739827594` and I renamed it, so be careful with that. If can not solve it, please post a question.

Comment: hey umm how do you call the second controller? What route? Do we need to compact anything with it?

Comment: What do you mean the second controller? The Auth Controller route is written up there, and you also need another route for the `GetAccounts()` controller, this is why we use routes. You need to call the function with a route. Compact is just about returning something to the view or somewhere else, it has nothing to do with the function call. If you want to get specific account info, you need to post some id with the route as a post request, and your controller will handle it. I believe you definitely should read the Laravel documents.